# Displaying object inside object in kendo grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, grid

I new with kendo and I have problem with kendo grid. I have structure like this

```
var data = [{
    key1: value1,
    key2: value2,
    objectInside: [{
        insideKey1: insideValue1,
        insideKey2: insideValue2,
        insideKey3: insideValue3
    },
    {
        insideKey1: insideValue1a,
        insideKey2: insideValue2a,
        insideKey3: insideValue3a
    },
    {
        insideKey1: insideValue1b,
        insideKey2: insideValue2b,
        insideKey3: insideValue3b
    }]
}];
```

and I need to create kendo grid and fill it with *objectInside* elements. For now I can display one of the element of the array:

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    pageable: true,
    selectable: "row",
    dataSource: data
    columns   : [
        { field: "objectInside.insideKey1[0]", title: "Value1:" },
        { field: "objectInside.insideKey2[0]", title: "Value2:" },
        { field: "objectInside.insideKey3[0]", title: "Value3:" }
    ]
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

But I do not have idea how to reach all the elements. Without indexing it doesn't work. It is possible to make loop here? I thought about making another variable contain only objectInside and try to read only this element but I failed here too. I try to do it like this:

```
var newData = data.objectInside;
```

or

```
var newData = JSON.stringify(data.objectInside);
```

Could anyone give me a hint how to deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [template](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.template):

```
{ template: "#= data.objectInside[0].insideKey1 #", title: "Value1" },
{ template: "#= data.objectInside[1].insideKey2 #", title: "Value2" },
{ template: "#= data.objectInside[2].insideKey3 #", title: "Value3" }
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/orOBu)

But this will show only one row, because the grid data contains one item in the first level. You can do [like this](http://dojo.telerik.com/orOBu/3) to show all your data inside `insideObject`.